# I need to disable Vue.js devtools for production mode but it should be enabled for development mode

Tags: vue.js, webpack, config

I don’t want my users to inspect the app using devtools so I would like to disable it in the production mode. But I need it in local/development mode. I have tried the below but it is not working.

I have created .env and .env.production files with a variable `VUE_APP_ROOT_API`

*.env file*

`VUE_APP_ROOT_API=http://localhost`

*.env.production*

`VUE_APP_ROOT_API=https://prod.com`

in webpack configuration, I have added below

`devtool: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API === ‘PROD’ ? ‘source-map’ : ‘’`

Please help me.

Comment: The `devtool` config incorrectly checks for `PROD` while your env sets `http://localhost` or `https://prod.com`. The config should be `devtool: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API === 'http://localhost' ? 'source-map' : ''` or `devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '' : 'source-map'`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  devtools.connect(/* host, port */)
}
```

Comment: Do you think what I have added in the env files is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `vue-cli` to generate your vue project then you do not have to do anything but just run the build commands:

```
npm run build
```

or

```
yarn build
```

It will have production mode enabled by default and the vue dev tools disabled.
Docs here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build

Otherwise just bundle your application in production mode as described here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#With-Build-Tools

In both cases dev tools should be disabled

Comment: I have not used default vue cli. My project is a customized setup.

Comment: then just create a production build and you should be ready to go. no extra code needed https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#With-Build-Tools

Comment: Yes, adding mode as production works! but every time I have to manually change the mode of development or production. I am searching for a solution that can achieve this without any manual work. Please let me know if you know something like that.